# Python method overriding issue

Tags: python, inheritance, overriding

Sample codes that show my issue:

```
class Parent:
    def one(self):
        print("Parent's one method")
    def another(self):
        print("Parent's another method")
        self.one()

class Child(Parent):
    def one(self):
        print("Child's one method")
    def another(self):
        print("Child's another method")
        super().another()
```

Now, when I run these codes:

```
c = Child()
c.another()
```

I got:

```
Child's another method
Parent's another method
Child's one method
```

which isn't quite what I expected. I would expect the last line be "Parent's one method".

So what's happening here? Is there a way to make sure that `super().another()` calls `Parent.one()` instead?

Comment: It's simple, in `Parent.another`, `self` is a `Child` instance, so `self.one()` resolves to `Child.one` since that has been overriden in `Child`

Comment: You *could* have `Parent.another` explicitly call `Parent.one(self)` but this to me screams poor design

Comment: You could avoid having to call Parent.one(self) by not overriding one() in the Child class, if that’s an option in your situation.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga, Now I see why, thanks for the explanation.

Comment: @LoganElandt, yeah, I think it's possible, I will try to avoid the situation described here.